# Javascript (shopping cart) showing up under other content?

Tags: javascript, css

Hey guys I'm a newbee as far as css and javascript go.  New theme I'm using is making my paypal minicart show up under the content so you can't click on it, nor delete stuff from it, but you can see the cart a little bit behind other stuff.  How do I make my minicart render on very top of all the other css and other javascript...?  Any help much appreciated

minicart js code is hosted on my server, this is what i put in the home page:

```
<script src="/files/minicart.min.js"></script>
<script>
        paypal.minicart.render();
</script>
```

I have a live chat window (JS) that seems to be on top but can't figure out how to make my "view shopping cart" button and shopping cart popup be on top too.

As for viewing the shopping cart my button looks like this but its still not 100% on top:

```
<div style="padding: 5px 0 0 5px; height: 100%; width: 10%;position:fixed;right:0;top:0">
<form><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="image" width="30" src="http://trydeal.com/files/gray_cart.png" align="right" name="submit">
</form></div>
```

Temp site is located at at: http://trydeal.com/test

Comment: what do you mean with "on top"?

Comment: If you want an html element on top of another, you can use the css attribute z-index. Just google z-index you'll find documentation on it.

Comment: @RyanSmith put it in an answer for i think that's what he needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add the z-index attribute to the element using my browser. Add it to your CSS and it will be fixed!

```
.minicart-showing #PPMiniCart {

   z-index: 1000 !important;       

}
```

[image]

Comment: AWESOME, z-index: 1000 !important; fixed it.  I should really learn more about css, it seems cool to work with.  Thanks a ton bud.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is because of z-index for "body > #wrapper > section" div.
To fix this issue you can give "#PPMiniCart" more z-index.

```
#PPMiniCart {
  left: 49%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```